# Server fault: reached question limit

Tags: support, serverfault, account

This is my profile on server fault: https://serverfault.com/users/178670/realtebo?tab=questions&sort=activity

I am not here to ask to remove by block. I ask you to explain what make me fall into the question limit and what to do to reenable my account. Or where is wrote when it will we removed automatically or where is wrote that it is permanent.

I cannot create new questions.

> You have reached your question limit

I read this in the doc

> How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> Begin by improving your existing questions: do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic.
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh the cost of those questions which were poorly received.

I have only one open question, older ones are answered.

**EDIT: thanks for explaining me that deleting bad questions was a bad idea. In these cases, I must upgrade the question, at least try to do it, not delete.**

I add only an example of what causes me problem. For example, see the deleted question, if you can: ["Apache slow serving a single page on a new VPS "](https://serverfault.com/questions/518273/apache-slow-serving-a-single-page-on-a-new-vps)

I asked help for diagnose.

I got 2 downvotes and only this comment:

> "OS? Log file entries? Anything? This question lacks about every necessary detail."

I understand reason behind the comment, a lot less the downvotes. But If I ask help for diagnose, the problem is I have no idea about *where and how* search for infos. If you ask me 'logs' I ask myseld: "which logs !?", "where are these logs",  ... of course not 'what are logs', but I do not ask help in diagnostic if I am able to lookup info for that diagnostic.

I added this info just to not overload comments of this question.

I known that my reaction, delete a question, is not good. I want to leave my experience here to discourage the same behaviours in the future users.

Reading more on this very meta, I read the sentence "this is not a forum".

Right. **The problem is that: if you need a forum you are in the wrong place.**. You will loose your *privilege* (not is a *right* ) to ask here if your do not accept the house's rules. This is good.

Comment: Please see [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/189912)

Comment: "Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways." ... Bad news for me. It is hard to have something useful to say when I have no useful to ask. I am pretty sure to have seen a 6 months period stated somewhere... Amen. Adios.

Comment: Found "If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask one new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.". So a timeout is present or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please note that you're only **banned from asking** new questions, you are **still allowed to post answers**, and highly encouraged to do so. Please pay it forward.

Please see [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/189912)

Typically limits take deleted questions into account as well.

By design the user interface hides deleted posts, but unfortunately they are even hidden from the user who posted them.

AFAIK Only once you achieve [>10k rep](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (or become moderator) a search of [`deleted:1`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user%3A178670+deleted%3A1) combined with your user ID will list the deleted questions and answers for your user.

[image: all your questions]

I think you should be able to follow these links and see the deleted questions:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/882202/bacula-jop-sends-2-times-the-same-notification
- https://serverfault.com/questions/831305/aws-ec2ebs-how-to-preserve-data-when-recreating-instances
- https://serverfault.com/questions/717196/vps-need-not-a-lot-of-space-but-4gb-of-ram-for-a-limited-time-where-to-buy-it
- https://serverfault.com/questions/518296/bind-dns-not-spreaded
- https://serverfault.com/questions/518273/apache-slow-serving-a-single-page-on-a-new-vps

Comment: So deleting do not helped me. I was the person who deleted these questions. And so now... ? Wait 6 months?

Comment: @MichaelHampton posted the link with the complete answer in his comment:  [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/189912)

Comment: Yes, thanks, in that page I read about 6 month period : "If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask one new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated."

Comment: @realtebo Even moderators don't know _all_ of the parameters of this automatic system, but we do know that if your question is deleted it counts against you. Deleting your own question after it gets downvotes is one way to ensure you get banned. As the system has explained, the thing to do is to _improve_ such questions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Yes, I understood, in the future I'll try. In past, when was clear that a question wass uselles/duplicated, I choosed to delete to avoid tons of downvotes. My questions was _evidently_ not good, but in many case there was nothing to do. I actually tend to avoid stack exhange in favour of forums when I need a more "discussion-like" approach, and to came here when I have enough info about the problem to at least ask a decent question. The problem is when I am so confused that I need clarifications on a problem, this kind of question are now welcome and I'll respect it.

Comment: I know and I admit that it is independent from you (=mods), but I think this score statistics is far not enough bad to deserve a ban. Most of his questions remained essentially unreacted, but nearly all of them survived the closure. I think the problem of his questions was that we couldn't answer them and not that they had been bad.

Comment: @realtebo Collect many rep, by writing many answers. There are a big topical overlap between the SE sites, while their community standards and voting customs may hugely different; I am not sure that the SF is the best starting site for you, with its particularly strict entry requirements.

Comment: @realtebo The answer to your apache error log question is probably that you get https or ajp traffic on a http port, or some similar. The most typical reason is misconfigured apache (if you don't set up the keys and `SSLEngine On`, apache listens as http on :443 without any problem or even a warning), if you are in hardcore java environment, then also AJP is possible. But that binary traffic looks more https than ajp on the first spot.